# Simplify the calcuation involving matrix inversions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis

Here is a question from my research project and what is already given as follows:

A: a symmetric positive definite matrix (SPD) of size N*N;

c: a column vector of size N;

$e_j$: a column vector filled with all zeros except for element j which is one.

Question: As $A$ is a very large array, is it possible to get $d$ without calculating $A^{-1}$ first? i.e., how to quickly calculate $d$? ($d$ need to be calculated for different index $j$.)

$d = \frac{e_j e_j^T A^{-1}c}{e_j^TA^{-1}e_j}$

Thank you.

Comment: You do not really need $A^{-1}$. What you really need is $e_{j}^{\top} A^{-1}$. Note that $f = e_{j}^{\top} A^{-1}$ is equivalent to $f \, A = e_{j}^{\top}$. By transposing this equality, you have : $e_{j} = A^{\top} f^{\top}$. Therefore, $f^{\top}$ is the solution of a linear system. There are methods which allow you to solve such linear systems more effectively than by computing $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Could you give more hint how to get the $f^T$ as fast as possible?

Comment: The syntax depends on the language but in almost every language you will find a library to do linear algebra and solve linear systems. In Matlab, you would write : `f = A\ej; f = f';`.

Comment: Thank you but this may not work. As I need to calculate $d$ for different index $j$. The solution you gave may be even slower than solving $A^{-1}$ first, so I can store $A^{-1}$ and do the multiplication for different $e_j$. Anyway, thanks for your input.